# Creating a sortable table (with React.js) that was produced using Flask and Bootstrap

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

I've got a table that I've created using Flask by getting data from an API and later compiling it into a table with bootstrap as a front end. I want to make the headers clickable in order to sort them, I've heard that React.js might be a good option for this, is there anyway for me to use React directly with my table without rewriting the entire app in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly! If you can install react then you should be able to use a library such as the [react-collapsing-table](https://github.com/massmutual/react-collapsing-table/). You would need to install it with npm then you should be able to import/require it on your page and just do

```
<ReactCollapsingTable rows={data} columns={columns} />
```

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a [react-bootstrap-table2](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/) frontend with a flask backend here: http://thomaxxl.pythonanywhere.com/ja/index.html#/books (no sorting implemented there but it is possible by using the appropriate react-bootstrap-table syntax: https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/basic-sort.html )

You can implement sorting in the backend or the frontend.

- To implement it in the backend, your api must support sorting parameters (eg. in the query string: ?sort=title,id )
- To implement sorting in the frontend you must fetch all your data which is not feasible for large tables

Other things you may want to consider are pagination, filtering and search.